# Running a .Net application in a sandbox

Tags: c#, .net, sandbox

Over the months, I've developed a personal tool that I'm using to compile C# 3.5 Xaml projects online. Basically, I'm compiling with the CodeDom compiler. I'm thinking about making it public, but the problem is that it is -very-very- easy to do anything on the server with this tool.

The reason I want to protect my server is because there's a 'Run' button to test and debug the app (in screenshot mode).

Is this possible to run an app in a sandbox - in other words, limiting memory access, hard drive access and BIOS access - without having to run it in a VM? Or should I just analyze every code, or 'disable' the Run mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spin up an AppDomain, load assemblies in it, look for an interface you control, Activate up the implementing type, call your method.  Just don't let any instances cross that AppDomain barrier (including exceptions!) that you don't 100% control.

Controlling the security policies for your external-code AppDomain is a bit much for a single answer, but you can [check this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568%28VS.100%29.aspx) or just search for "code access security msdn" to get details about how to secure this domain.

**Edit**:  There are exceptions you cannot stop, so it is important to watch for them and record in some manner the assemblies that caused the exception so you will not load them again.

Also, it is always better to *inject* into this second AppDomain a type that you will then use to do all loading and execution.  That way you are ensured that no type (that won't bring down your entire application) will cross any AppDomain boundary.  I've found it is useful to define a type that extends MarshalByRefObject that you call methods on that executes insecure code in the second AppDomain.  It should never return an unsealed type that isn't marked Serializable across the boundary, either as a method parameter or as a return type.  As long as you can accomplish this you are 90% of the way there.

Comment: Is this intended for a web application or for any .Net client code?

Comment: @LéonPelletier both.  You can spin up an AppDomain anywhere and any time.  However, you can't do this within the span of a single response in any application (browser particularly, and desktop as well).  So you have (if you want to keep your UI resopnsive) to do this on a different thread.  A little more complicated in a web application, but doable.  You just have to poll the website asynchronously and then redirect when done.

Comment: +1. @LéonPelletier - any .Net code. Note that even most strict CAS policy and code verification does not protect you completely - easiest thing is to create StackOverflowException with some recursive call to tear down app domain/process - requires only  lowest possible set of permissions (execute) .

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there definitely are exceptions that **cannot** be caught or handled.  Those are few and far between, but you can always record them, recover gracefully, and refrain from loading up the offensive assemblies again.  This is more important in a web application than on the desktop, of course.

Comment: Since it's a development platform, the average program needs to write user or config data, so it seems I'm better to manage it with VMs, and care more about CPU and permissions.

Comment: @LéonPelletier that seems a heavy burden to bear.  But one that guarantees isolation through machines.  You only have to worry about access to shared resources (disk, network, etc) in that case.